# How can I send a null element using python requests?

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I am trying to send a POST request to an API, which needs a "session" parameter, set to null.
This is the payload sent from my web browser :
`{"session":null,"query":{"__type":"SelectListQuery:http://dev.docuware.com/settings/organization"}}`

And this is what I'm trying, using the python requests package (return is WIP, and not relevant to the issue):

```
    def get_all_fixed_lists_guid(self, s):
        headers = {'Authorization': self.token}
        url = f'{self.url}/DocuWare/Settings/SettingsService.svc/jwt/GetSelectLists'
        payload = {"session": json.dumps(None), "query": {
            "__type": "SelectListQuery:http://dev.docuware.com/settings/organization"}}
        response = s.request('POST', url, json=payload, timeout=30)
        print(response.content)
        return response.status_code == 200
```

URL and token are corrects. From what I read on the subject, I can't send a null parameter using the requests package.

From what I understand, everything I tried sends a string, but an "Element" is expected.
How can I solve it ?

Those are the various thing I tried to send :

- `None`
- `json.dumps(None)`
- `"null"`
- `False`
- `json.dumps(False)`
- not passing the parameter at all.

Aside from the last one, this is the error message I get back from the server:

```
b'{"ExceptionType":"System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException",
"FaultCode":"Sender","Message":"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http:\\/\\/dev.docuware.com\\/services\\/settings:session. 
The InnerException message was \'Expecting state \'Element\'.. Encountered \'Text\'  with name \'\', namespace \'\'. \'.  Please see InnerException for more details.",
"StackTrace":" at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, PartInfo returnInfo, Object& returnValue) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyCore(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)"}'
```

I'm expecting a 200 status code with a json object, instead of the 400 status code and above error.

Comment: just put `{"session": None}` without dumping ?

Comment: This is the result I get by doing so : b'{"ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","FaultCode":"NULL","Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: This looks like an issue with the API and not whether `requests` is sending `null` or not.

Comment: Well @axe319 I would agree with you if it wasn't working when performing the operations in the browser :-/

Comment: `requests` absolutely will convert `None` to `null` in `json`. It uses either `simplejson` or `json` depending on whether you have `simplejson` installed. You can view the source code for that [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/models.py#L511). Here, `complexjson` is either `simplejson` or `json` as defined [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/compat.py#L32). If you want to mirror that to prove it you can just `import json` and `json.dumps({'data': None}, allow_nan=False)` which results in `'{"data": null}'`.

Comment: As an aside, you're setting the variable `headers` but doing nothing with it.